# Bootstrap row with two columns and textareas fill up page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a simple page that have a header on a row, then a row with two columns. Each column will include a textarea. I want the columns and the textareas to fill up the rest of the page. I have been searching but i can't solve this. I'm using boostrap v4.0.0-beta.2.

Here is my snippet:

```css
  label { font-weight: bold; }
            html, body, .container-fluid {
                height: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
            }
            textarea.form-control {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background: #DDDDDD">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12 jumbotron text-center">
           <h1>Formatter</h1>
           <p>Enter raw input to see output</p> 
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" style="background: #CCCCCC;">
       <div class="col-lg-6">
           <label for="input">Input:</label>
           <textarea class="form-control" id="input">
           </textarea>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-6">
           <label for="output">Output:</label>
           <textarea readonly class="form-control" id="output"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the height of the column/text area to be the rest of the height of the page?

Comment: Yes, that is what i want.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you set Height of text area to 100%. But it depend on its parent div. 100% means 100% of its parent div.

So either you have to change all of its parent divs styles or if you are ok with CSS3 you can use viewport percentage units like  `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`(it means 100% of the viewport/ window size).

```
textarea.form-control {
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by set window height with jQuery .height() function. You can check snippet but remember to add jQuery file.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var textareaHeight = $(window).height();
    $(".form-control").height(textareaHeight - 30);
  });
```

```css
label { font-weight: bold; }
            html, body, .container-fluid {
                height: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
            }
            textarea.form-control {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background: #DDDDDD">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12 jumbotron text-center">
           <h1>Formatter</h1>
           <p>Enter raw input to see output</p> 
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" style="background: #CCCCCC;">
       <div class="col-lg-6">
           <label for="input">Input:</label>
           <textarea class="form-control" id="input">
           </textarea>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-6">
           <label for="output">Output:</label>
           <textarea readonly class="form-control" id="output"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting `height` to `textarea` with `JS`. You have to compute height needed to fill the page